# UITesting xcode 2015

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, wwdc

I have watched about UITesting in wwdc 2015 and I start to record. Procedure is that when user tap on tableview, I make request to API. However, it look like request is calling again and again. Also, it doesn't go to next page already. If I just run app without recording, it is okay. May I know what is the possible causes for this?

Comment: can you paste some code or scree in your question, that can help in understanding your problem. Currently the question is vey unclear.

Comment: Hi Sandy, UI testing code isn't generated yet because it keep calling the web service and it look like application hang forever.